# "not an X509 code-signing certificate" when trying to sign adobe air app

Tags: air, openssl, certificate, x509certificate, sign

I am trying to sign my first adobe air app, but it fails with "not an X509 code-signing certificate". There are a few threads about this on the web, most of which revert to using a self-signed cert with "adt -certificate" and I don't want to use it, I have a trusted cert I want to use instead, so I'm still unable to get this to work after many hours of headbang...

My key + certificate are from godadday, just in case, I converted the .crt file to x509 before creating the keystore.p12 file (I did not change/convert the .key file):

openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -inform PEM -out mycert509.pem -outform PEM
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert509.pem -inkey mykey.key -out keystore.p12 -passout 'pass:xxxx'

And here is my ANE build cmdline:

"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\sdks\4.6.0\bin\adt" -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "keystore.p12" -storepass "xxxx" -target ane MyANE.ane extension.xml -swc MyAir.swc  -platform Android-ARM -C android . -platform default -C default .

But still I get the error...
Any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: First of all, did you purchase a code signing certificate? "SSL certificate" won't work.

Comment: No sure what you mean, I have a key + certificate, purchased from godaddy, I use them on my website. Are you saying that it cannot be used specifically for CODE signing?

Comment: if you use them on the web site, this means that the certificate was issued for SSL/TLS. This is a different usage purpose, than code signing, and such certificate can't be used to sign code. You need to purchase code signing certificate.

Comment: thanks, I guess this is the cause in my case :)